# Can't add a view to XML layout from code

Tags: java, android, layout, android-edittext

I have those code:

```
public class ContentEditText extends EditText {
/*
 * Constructors
 */
public ContentEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
{
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public ContentEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
}

public ContentEditText(Context context)
{
    super(context);
}

/*
 * Listener
 */
@Override   
protected void onSelectionChanged(int selStart, int selEnd)
{ 
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "selStart is " + selStart + "selEnd is " + selEnd, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}   
}
```

and

```
public class Main extends Activity {
private LinearLayout mainLayout;
private Button bBT;
private Button uBT;
private Button iBT;
private Button lBT;
private EditText titleET;
private ContentEditText contentET;
private Markup markup;

/** onCreate Function */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    initLayout();     
    setContentView(mainLayout);           
}

private void initLayout()
{
    // initialize some components by XML layout
    mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
    bBT = (Button) findViewById(R.id.boldBT);
    uBT = (Button) findViewById(R.id.underlineBT);
    iBT = (Button) findViewById(R.id.italicBT);
    lBT = (Button) findViewById(R.id.listBT);
    titleET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.titleET);
    // initialize a EditText programmatically
    contentET = new ContentEditText(this);
    contentET.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
    contentET.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    // add the EditText to the main layout
    mainLayout.addView(contentET);
}
```

I thought I add contentET to the main layout by the right way, but it doesn't work, the LogCat said "NullPointerException" for variable contentET, I don't know why. Anyone can tell me where did i do wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chang your code to this as the first call should be `setContentView` after the `super`. Since this is not the case in your above code you are trying to access the layout without `inflating` it there fore it throwing `nullpointer` exception

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_xml_file);           
    initLayout();
}
```

Comment: it's still the same error: NullPointerException, and the Logcat points to the line: setContentView(mainLayout);

Comment: ahh, sorry, i missed reading your answer carefully, it should be setContentView(R.layout.your_xml_file);, it works perfectly. Thanks :)